# Removing a model from a collection removes the View's reference

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my application I have a case of two views sharing the same model.

I am having trouble when I am accessing the collection through the model and removing the model from the collection. The problem is that after calling `this.model.collection.remove(this.model)` the view's reference `this.model` is undefined.

The reason I am not unbinding the events before removing is, that I need `mySecondView` to be able to know about the remove event inorder to remove it's self from the DOM.

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events : {
        'click .delete' : deleteModel
    }

    initialize : function() {

        this.model.on('remove', this.dispose, this)
    },


    deleteModel : function() {

        if( this.model.isNew() )
        {

            this.model.collection.remove( this.model );

            //remove all the events bound to the model
            this.model.unbind(); //this.model is undefined

            this.dispose();
        }

    }
});


MySecondView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize : function() {

        //call the custom dispose method to remove the view
        this.model.on('remove', this.dispose, this );
    }

});

myModel      = new Backbone.Model();    
myCollection = new Backbone.Collection( myModel );

myView       = new MyView({ model : myModel });
mySecondView = new MySecondView({ model : myModel });
```

The only way that works is by creating a local variable reference to the model in `deleteModel`

Any Suggestions?

Comment: When you [destroy](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-destroy) a model it fires a `destroy` event that bubbles up to the collection so you shouldn't need to call `this.model.collection.remove( this.model );`

Comment: this is a new Model which doesn't exist on the server and just needs to be deleted on the client side. I had a typing mistake which I fixed where I was calling `this.destroy` instead of `this.dispose`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a programming mistake.

When calling the `this.model.collection.remove( this.model );` a remove event was called on the model which was bound to the `dispose` method which removed any local references to the model. Hence the reference to the model was lost.